# How to count felicitation and discipline of employee in achievements system

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 record tables and staff, employee table including employee code, table record including employee code, id, type (bit).
If the employee makes a mistake, he will add 1 record with the employee code and type = 0; If an employee achieves achievement, add a new record with type = 1.
At the end of the month, it will summarize which employee has more merits of committing the reward (the total performance of an employee is calculated by the formula: (total type = 1) - (total type = 0))
Can I expect a code that can give me the results below?
total= felicitation - discipline

```
=================================================================
| EmployeeId    |  achievement   |   mistake     |   total      |
=================================================================
|      1        |        2        |         1        |    1     |
|      2        |        1        |         0        |    1     |
==================================================================
```

**Record**

```
======================|
| ID | Type |EmployeeId|
|=====================|
| 1  |  0   |   1     |
| 2  |  1   |   1     |
| 3  |  1   |   1     |
| 4  |  1   |   2     |
=======================
```

Tks for reading!

Comment: share sample data

Comment: @zaynul Abadin Tuhin I edited my question, tks for comment

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use conditional aggregation

```
   select EmployeeId,
   sum(Type=1) as achievement,
   sum(Type=0) as mistake,
   sum(Type=1)-sum(Type=0 ) as total
   from cte group by EmployeeId
```

[Demo link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f791c090fd9e753661796b277e78c50a)

```
EmployeeId  achievement      mistake       total
  1                2             1            1
  2                1             0            1
```

Comment: tks so much <3 happy coding

Comment: In MySQL you can simplify this to sum(type=0)